# Is there an easy way to integrate Sitecore v8.2 with a modern JavaScript Framework?

Tags: javascript, integration

As far as I know, Sitecore v8.2 is not using JSS.

My company is still using this version of the CMS and for many reasons, there is a stuck in upgrading it.

In any case, we would like to introduce a JavaScript framework Front End side to facilitate the work from Front End developers and to leverage the work Back End side.

So the question is: is there an easy way to integrate a modern JavaScript Framework (Angular - the most recent versions like 9 or 10 - or React or Vue or even some others modern ones) with Sitecore v8.2 keeping all the glorious functionality that this CMS is providing to the Content Editors, the Analytics, etc?

Comment: Would probably cost you more to set up than the cost of upgrading. It would also set you down further on a path of upgrade complication and non-standard implementation. Sitecore.React supports pre-JSS versions of Sitecore.

Comment: Totally agree with @MarkCassidy. Later on upgrade will be a nightmare.

Comment: Sitecore.React was designed to do exactly what you want and started out on 8.2 - while the current version is built against the 9.x binaries, the codebase should work fine on 8.2 still. Shameless self promotion here, I wrote Sitecore.React - https://github.com/GuitarRich/sitecore.react

Comment: There is a stuck with many old legacy code that is a complete mess, that is not supported by Sitecore version 9+, this is why we are not upgrading immediately. This will require months to recover. But Front End wants to introduce the framework, so I for look at this Sitecore.React. Thanks